# How to write CSS rule only for default Android Browser using @media queries?

Tags: android, css

I need to apply **CSS** rule only for default Android Browser using **@media** queries. Not for Chrome, but for default browser in Android.

Does such query exist?

Important to say, that there are too many different Android devices with different sceen sizes. So, using `max-width` in `@media` can't solve my problem.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Based on the [media query spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) it doesn't seem like there are any queries to suit your needs. However this can easily be done in js by checking the user agent

Comment: @akash93, ok, how can I check user agent and determine that this is default Android browser and not Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [CSS3 media query specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) it's not possible to detect using just media queries.

However using javascript the default android browser (not chrome) can be detected using the following snippet

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_android_native = ((ua.indexOf('mozilla/5.0') > -1 && ua.indexOf('android ') > -1 && ua.indexOf('applewebkit') > -1) && !(ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1));
```